# NoSQL Database for real-time, two-player Facebook Game

Tags: database, nosql

I am in the middle of developing a real-time, two player and turn-based Facebook Game. I have almost done the JavaScript code that includes the mechanics of the game but I still don't have the game implemented as two player and real time.

I have read some articles and asked some questions that say that MySQL database is not what I need. I need to use NoSQL. I want to ask for suggestions and these are the things to be considered:

- Players are on Facebook so I need to display their friends, and indicate whether a friend has already played the game or not.
- I also need to implement a real-time game request sending. It is a two-player and turn-based game so, Player 1 must ask Player 2's permission first before they go for a battle.
- I would also want to store players' game info. I want to include gold, items, and energy stuff (like most of the famous Facebook games). These details must be updated real quick as the players play and achieve some goals.
- I am running Windows on my local computer and I will use this as my test server. But I am planning to have a Linux based server in the future. So compatibility is still an issue.

Comment: Why do you think that a mySQL database is unsuitable for your project? I see nothing in your requirements which points one way or the other regarding database choice.

Comment: @Philipp - I have done some research and I have found out that NoSQL is more capable of handling huge databases. Can you please help me decide? Consider that I need a real-time, two-player and turn-based Facebook Game.

Comment: no, I can not help you, because all the factors you describe are irrelevant for choosing a database technology. You could start by describing how your **data** is structured. But even then it's primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/). It is easy to run/manage. It uses JSON for data storage, which is great for Javascript based applications as it's a native data structure.

It's very popular amongst gaming companies. It's lightning fast (it's memcached + persistence in a single layer, so we're talking RAM speed) and scales super easily. You would still need to build a REST API service in front of Couchbase to serve your needs, but since the schema is flexible, it is a breeze to build your data model.

If you need help figuring that out, ping me [@scalabl3](http://twitter.com/scalabl3).

Answer (score -1):

check [rethinkdb](https://www.rethinkdb.com), is use to realtime.

> Use cases where companies benefited from RethinkDB’s realtime push architecture include:
>
> Collaborative web and mobile apps
>
> - Streaming analytics apps
> - Multiplayer games
> - Realtime marketplaces
> - Connected devices